# Can we create a HoC or composition that accepts a component and adds and applies additional props to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components

We have created a component that returns a custom `textfield`(with our custom css and props) something like this:

```js
const customTextFieldAvailable = (props) => {
  const { handleOnchange, onBlur, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField onChange={handleOnchange} onBlur={onBlur} />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

What I want is that some extra props be added and applied to the `textfield` of this custom fields (Notice this accepts as well as applies additional props, say `autocomplete` , `autofocus` etc) roughly like this:

```js
const customTextFeildsWithExtraProps = (props) => {
  const {
       size,
       onChange,
        onBlur,
        value,
        autoComplete,
        autoFocus,
        type,
        onKeyPress,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField
        size="small"
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        value={value}
        autoComplete={autocomplete}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        type={type}
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

How can I create an HoC or composition to achieve this? Or Is there any way to achieve this without modifying the original component `customTextFieldAvailable`?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question :], can u elaborate?

Comment: @felixmosh Sure I elaborated further. Is that clear or shall I expand on this a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. Your TextField component will just need to accept the props that are being passed to it. You can either handle them individually, or just accept all props that are passed to TextField as `...rest` and spread them onto whatever underlying component you're using.

That being said, if you're already accepting rest props on your existing wrapper component, I don't think you need to build another one, as it will do the same thing once you pass `{...other}` to the TextField

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control on the available component so I can't modify it. What I can best do it create another component that takes this as a paramter and adds the additional params (something like HoC)